# Unable to install IJulia failed to clone from repository error

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I tried

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

And everytime I am getting the same error

```
Cloning default registries into C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\.julia\registries
   Cloning registry General from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, failed to send request: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
)
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:120
 [2] #clone#2(::String, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,LibGit2.CachedCredentials,Tuple{Symbol},NamedTuple{(:credentials,),Tuple{LibGit2.CachedCredentials}}}, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\GitTools.jl:107
 [3] #clone at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [4] (::getfield(Pkg.Types, Symbol("##51#55")))(::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:933
 [5] shred!(::getfield(Pkg.Types, Symbol("##51#55")), ::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at .\secretbuffer.jl:184
 [6] #registries#50(::Bool, ::Function) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:929
 [7] registries at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:913 [inlined]
 [8] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:307 [inlined]
 [9] update_registry(::Pkg.Types.Context) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:97
 [10] #handle_repos_add!#32(::Bool, ::Nothing, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:607
 [11] #handle_repos_add! at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [12] #add_or_develop#13(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:54
 [13] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [14] #add_or_develop#12 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:29 [inlined]
 [15] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [16] #add_or_develop#11 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:28 [inlined]
 [17] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [18] #add_or_develop#10 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:27 [inlined]
 [19] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [20] #add#18 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [21] add(::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:69
 [22] top-level scope at none:0
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: OK so after you said me that it can be a firewall issue, I was using my college wifi until now to download IJulia so I changed it to my personal hotspot and tried installing it again and it worked. Can you please tell me why and how . What was the issue??

Comment: I just saw the error message was "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally", which probably means that something was blocking the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I guess a firewall issue. I was working on my institution wifi. And then I changed it to my personal hotspot and tried installing it again and it worked.